# Is there a way to disable custom mappings while plugin functions are being executed in vim?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, plugin-system

In my vimrc file, I use the following few lines to swap backtick and single-quote for convenience when I'm using marks:

```
for first in ['', 'g', '[', ']']
    for mode in ['n', 'x', 'o']
        exe mode . "noremap " . first . "' " . first . "`"
        exe mode . "noremap " . first . "` " . first . "'"
    endfor
endfor
```

This works great, but has the unfortunate side effect of breaking a plugin I use due to the plugin's internal use of marks. The plugin in question is the awesome and awesomely-named [ninja-feet.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet), but my question isn't really about any plugin in particular. Is there a good way to define the mappings so that they don't take effect when plugin functions are being executed? If not, what's the best way to resolve this issue?

I can think of a number of solutions that would fix my particular problem but they're basically all hacks, so I'm curious if there's a good general approach to solve these sorts of conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the plugins to use `nore` mappings and *banged* `:normal!` command as much as possible.

Sometimes it's not possible. That's why I don't like *swapping* some default keybindings.

What you can do is to implement a mechanism to activate/deactivate your mappings before using mappings and commands from other plugins. I have a very old plugin on the subject: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/Triggers.vim

Another possibility is to try to inject your changes in the mappings defined by the plugins you use. But as the plugin seems to play with `feedkeys()` I'm afraid it'll be much more complex.